# How to obtain claim numbered within proof without changing the default look

Tags: amsmath, amsthm

I have a problem that I could not solve, even after looking around for a while on the site.

Quite simply, I do like how the following MWE looks like in terms of spacing, but I would like to have the claims numbered within each proof starting from 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} There are some claims.
\begin{claim}
Bla
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
Bla bla
\end{claim}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} There are some claims.
\begin{claim}
Bla
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
Bla bla
\end{claim}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that all the solutions I found modified in some way the present spacing between the objects, which is the default look.

Is it possible to avoid such a situation?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you want.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{claim}{0}}
```

Here we reset the `claim` counter after each `proof` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
%\numberwithin{claim}{theorem} %% <-- This is another alternative if you like little difference.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{claim}{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} There are some claims.
\begin{claim}
Bla
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
Bla bla
\end{claim}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} There are some claims.
\begin{claim}
Bla
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
Bla bla
\end{claim}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clean and smooth. Great answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wondering, a sudden curiosity. In case I would like to have only one unnumbered claim, how could I obtain it? (e.g. assume that in theorem 2 there is only one claim, which I would leave unnumbered) Thanks a lot, and sorry for the late curiosity.

Comment: @Kolmin `\newtheorem*` is for such purposes. Declare `\newtheorem*{myclaim}{Claim}` and then `\begin{myclaim}...\end{myclaim}` will not be numbered.

Comment: since you're using `amsthm`, you should be able to use `\qedhere` before the last `\end{claim}` to move the tombstone up to the last line, not have it on a line by itself.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks a lot! I knew I could do it in such a way, but I thought that maybe there was another option.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks a lot! That's really useful. Yesterday I was reading some Q/A exactly on this issue.